# on back button click the seelcted value of the dropdown with languages doesn't change

Tags: jquery

I've got one simple partial view

```
@model List<MvcBeaDAL.LanguageHost> 

@using (Html.BeginForm("SetLanguage","Home", new {returnURL =ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery }))
{ 
   @Html.DropDownList("langIDD", new SelectList(Model,"LanCd","Descr",@ViewBag.Selected), new { id = "langIDD" });
}
```

which has the dropdown wrapped in a form. When the value of teh dropdown changes (the language changes) - I make request to the mvc action that just changes the language of the url and reloads the page with the new language!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#langIDD").change(function () {
        $(this).parents("form").submit();
    });

});
```

The problem  with this dropdown when I press the  "Back" button  of the browser - if I change the language and then  press 'back' button as expected the page is reloaded with the previous language but unfortunately only the selected value of this dropdown doesn't change.

SO can someone help me how can I resolve this issue

Comment: Is it just me? I don't see any jQuery in your code.

Comment: OOof sorry I'm so worried that I forgot to post the code. Now I'm doing it

Comment: it will ofcourse reset

Comment: By "unfortunately only the selected value of this dropdown doesn't change", what do you mean? Can your elaborate?